# Loopback Installation: "The term 'lb4' is not recognized"

Tags: loopbackjs

I have installed the Loopbackjs and when I am trying to run lb4 command it is showing the error.

```
lb4: The term 'lb4' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
> function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
> name, or if a path was  included, verify that the path is correct and
> try again. At line:1 char:1
> + lb4 app
> + ~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (lb4:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException  
> 
> lb4: The term 'lb4' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
> function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
> name, or if a path was  included, verify that the path is correct and
> try again. At line:1 char:1
> + lb4 app
> + ~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (lb4:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Any suggestion to solve this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CLI tool `lb4` is shipped in the npm package `@loopback/cli`. You need to install this package globally. See [Getting Started](https://loopback.io/getting-started.html):

> **STEP 2**
>
> **Install LoopBack 4 CLI**
>
> The LoopBack 4 CLI is a command-line interface that can scaffold a project or extension. The CLI provides the fastest way to get started with a LoopBack 4 project that adheres to best practices.
>
> ```
> $ npm install -g @loopback/cli
> ```

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote
>   If you faced this kind of problem please make sure that npm is installed globally. and check also that node is properly insatlled.